# PHP Remove http and web domain from url

Tags: php, substr

I want http and web domain removed in a url and render the rest

URL | Expected result

http://www.loadedcamp.net/images/featured/2017/06/1497262523-How_to_Avoid_Adultery_in_Your_Marriage.jpg | /images/featured/2017/06/1497262523-How_to_Avoid_Adultery_in_Your_Marriage.jpg

http://www.loadedcamp.net/music/63637-adele-hello | /music/63637-adele-hello

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here with `parse_url()` function.

```
parse_url('http://www.loadedcamp.net/music/63637-adele-hello', PHP_URL_PATH);
```

Output: `/music/63637-adele-hello`

Answer (score 3):

You can php `parse_url()` method to get the complete info of URL:

```
$foo = "http://www.loadedcamp.net/music/63637-adele-hello";
$blah = parse_url($foo);
print_r($blah);
Array
(
    [scheme] => http
    [host] => www.loadedcamp.net
    [path] => /music/63637-adele-hello
    [query] => 
)

print_r($blah['path']);
```

Outputs `/music/63637-adele-hello`

You can also use like this:

```
echo parse_url('http://www.loadedcamp.net/music/63637-adele-hello', PHP_URL_PATH);
```

Also outputs `/music/63637-adele-hello`